# In Xamarin, Use OnIdiom with OnIdiom

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Why MergedWith ResourceDictionary attribute's doesn't support OnIdiom feature ?
This code works good:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedWith>theme:PhoneTheme</ResourceDictionary.MergedWith>
```

This one set the MergedWith property to null :

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedWith>
    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:String">
        <OnIdiom.Phone>theme:PhoneTheme</OnIdiom.Phone>
        <OnIdiom.Tablet>theme:TabletTheme</OnIdiom.Tablet>
    </OnIdiom>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedWith>
```

Is there any solution to use a different theme between the phone idiom and the tablet idiom ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't currently do this in XAML at this stage, however you can work around it with a codebehind file. I use the Application xaml and codebehind to dynamically change the themes. Then just do the standard inheritance for the Phone and Tablet themes to common colors, styles, etc. Only overriding what is needed in each Iodiom specific theme.

*MyApp.xaml*

```
<Application ...>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Name="appTheme"> <!-- Name the Resource Dict //-->
        ...Any converters, etc
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application>
```

*MyApp.xaml.cs*

```
public partial class MyApp : Application
{
    public MyApp()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Toggle appTheme.MergedWith based on Idiom 
        appTheme.MergedWith = Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Phone ? typeof(PhoneTheme) : typeof(TabletTheme);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a good idea but after the merged resource dictionary is considered like a dynamic resource. It isn't very well for me.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't support right now, but has been [coined on the Xamarin Forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/86308/multiple-merged-dictionaries).

A workaround could be to create seperate pages for phone and tablet and dependent on the idiom show one page or the other. On that page you can have it's own theme. I guess that's the best you can do at this time.

Comment: Hum it's already I do but I wanted to simplify the idiom theming.
Thank's for your answer !