# Maui App.xaml load between two ResourceDictionary files based on "OnIdiom" for Tablet or Phone

Tags: maui, resourcedictionary

I have two Resource Dictionaries one for Mobile and one for Tablet and I would like to merge the correct one within App.xaml using OnIdiom.
With OnPlatform it is straight forward, but I am not seeing a way to do the same with OnIdiom to check if it is Tablet and then load the Tablet file or Phone file etc.

```
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Margins.xaml" />
                <!-- The two files below I would like to use OnIdiom to select between Tablet or Mobile -->
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/FixedSizesMobile.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/FixedSizesTablet.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Styles.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a fellow Discord Member, he pointed me in the right direction, I was over complicating it trying to follow OnPlatform functionality.

This Merges based on OnIdiom and is working nicely.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Margins.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source='{OnIdiom Phone="Resources/Styles/FixedSizesPhone.xaml"}' />
            <ResourceDictionary Source='{OnIdiom Tablet="Resources/Styles/FixedSizesTablet.xaml"}' />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Styles.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

> With OnPlatform it is straight forward, but I am not seeing a way to do the same with OnIdiom to check if it is Tablet and then load the Tablet file or Phone file etc.

Unfortunately it can't do that. I tried to use `OnIdiom` to modify it on XAML but failed. In addition, I also found this case: [In Xamarin, Use OnIdiom with OnIdiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43224015/in-xamarin-use-onidiom-with-onidiom). But it does not have `MergedWith` for MAUI, also `Device.Idiom` is [deprecated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ADqR.png).

For [controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/customize-ui-appearance?view=net-maui-8.0#customize-ui-appearance-based-on-the-device-idiom), [it works well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Utz1G.png).

You can report it as an issue or a feature request on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues).

Comment: If you check my Answer below, I have tested on multiple devices(emulators) now and it is working nicely, I was to stuck in trying to do it similar to OnPlatform and just missed the clear way as it was documented #facepalm.

Comment: I'm afraid it won't work like OnPlatform.